# Determining whether an object is a string or a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have some variables and single column dataframes.

I'm trying to arrange them (concat) into a single dataframe.

The problem is that some are single strings, some single column dataframes and I'm trying to loop through them, so I have to use different methods for the different types.

I've tried the following to determine if a single string or a dataframe is being passed.

```
data = {'Column Name':  ['First value', 'Second value']}
a_dataframe = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Column Name'])

a_single_string = 'text'
another_string = 'more text'

feature_cols = ['a_single_string', 'a_dataframe', 'another_string']

for column in feature_cols:
    if column in locals():
        if isinstance(column, str):
            print("str: " + column)

        elif isinstance(column, pd.DataFrame):
            print("df: " + column)
```

But it sees the strings and dataframe as strings.
Any solutions?

Comment: They are `str` though. You build the list `feature_cols` with `str` literals and then loop over them and check whether they are `str`. Maybe you could rephrase the question? Because I'm not exactly clear on what you're trying to do.

Comment: BTW, note that `"df: " + column` is a matrix operation. You probably want to do `print("df:", column)` instead, or better yet, `print("df:", column, sep='\n')` so that you don't mess with the df's formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code defines `feature_cols` as a list of strings. So your `isinstance()` test is returning the type of the string `'a_dataframe'`, which is not the same thing as the variable `a_dataframe`.

This will fix your test:

```
feature_cols = [a_single_string, a_dataframe, another_string]
```

You also won't be able to do `if column in locals():` because that expects the name as a string (as in your original code) not the variable.

Comment: I always get caught on that, however this presents the following `TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Comment: @Spatial You'll also need to remove the check `if column in locals():` That should be added to this answer.

Comment: That is because of your test `if column in locals():` Do you really need that? Thanks @SpatialDigger, you were ahead of me there.